# SSL Handshake failure with TLSv1 by using Java 6, HTMLUnit and Bouncy Castle

Tags: ssl, htmlunit, handshake, sslcontext

I am trying to connect SSL site https://link.bollore-logistics.com by using Java 6 and HTMLUnit, I have added more supported Ciphers by using Bouncy Castle. But still, I am receiving handshake failure. I cannot upgrade Java version due to production limitation. Please kindly help

Code of configuration:

```
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
            return true;
        }
    });

    if (Security.getProvider("BC") == null){
        logger.info("Bouncy Castle provider is NOT available");
    }
    else{
        logger.info("Bouncy Castle provider is available");
    }

    Provider provider = new BouncyCastleProvider();
    Security.addProvider(provider);

    SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");

    context.init(null, new X509TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager() {

        @Override
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) throws CertificateException {
        }

        @Override
        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
        }

        @Override
        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return null;
        }
    }}, new SecureRandom());



    String[] scs = context.getSocketFactory().getSupportedCipherSuites();
    Arrays.sort(scs);

    for(String s : scs) {
        System.out.println(s);
     }
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());


    // Create all-trusting host name verifier
    HostnameVerifier allHostsValid = new HostnameVerifier() {
        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
            return true;
        }
    };
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(allHostsValid);
```

Code to make connection (HTMLUnit):

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webClient.getPage(url);
```

Here is the error log:

```
2017-12-06 11:27:40 DEBUG WebClient:325 - Get page for window named '', using WebRequest[<url="http://link.bollore-logistics.com/Contact/SmartSearch/77707575", GET, EncodingType[name=application/x-www-form-urlencoded], [], {Accept-Encoding=gzip, deflate, Accept=*/*}, null>]
2017-12-06 11:27:40 DEBUG WebClient:1259 - Load response for GET http://link.bollore-logistics.com/Contact/SmartSearch/77707575
trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
2017-12-06 11:27:40 DEBUG RequestAddCookies:122 - CookieSpec selected: mine
2017-12-06 11:27:40 DEBUG RequestAuthCache:76 - Auth cache not set in the context
2017-12-06 11:27:40 DEBUG PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager:249 - Connection request: [route: {}->http://link.bollore-logistics.com:80][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 6; total allocated: 0 of 20]
2017-12-06 11:27:40 DEBUG PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager:282 - Connection leased: [id: 0][route: {}->http://link.bollore-logistics.com:80][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 1 of 6; total allocated: 1 of 20]
2017-12-06 11:27:40 DEBUG MainClientExec:234 - Opening connection {}->http://link.bollore-logistics.com:80
2017-12-06 11:27:40 DEBUG DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator:131 - Connecting to link.bollore-logistics.com/195.101.158.66:80
2017-12-06 11:27:40 DEBUG DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator:138 - Connection established 192.168.171.168:52556<->195.101.158.66:80
2017-12-06 11:27:40 DEBUG MainClientExec:255 - Executing request GET /Contact/SmartSearch/77707575 HTTP/1.1
2017-12-06 11:27:40 DEBUG MainClientExec:260 - Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
2017-12-06 11:27:40 DEBUG MainClientExec:266 - Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
2017-12-06 11:27:40 DEBUG headers:124 - http-outgoing-0 >> GET /Contact/SmartSearch/77707575 HTTP/1.1
2017-12-06 11:27:40 DEBUG headers:127 - http-outgoing-0 >> Host: link.bollore-logistics.com
2017-12-06 11:27:40 DEBUG headers:127 - http-outgoing-0 >> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36
2017-12-06 11:27:40 DEBUG headers:127 - http-outgoing-0 >> Accept-Language: en-US
2017-12-06 11:27:40 DEBUG headers:127 - http-outgoing-0 >> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
2017-12-06 11:27:40 DEBUG headers:127 - http-outgoing-0 >> Accept: */*
2017-12-06 11:27:40 DEBUG headers:127 - http-outgoing-0 >> Connection: Keep-Alive
2017-12-06 11:27:40 DEBUG wire:72 - http-outgoing-0 >> "GET /Contact/SmartSearch/77707575 HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
2017-12-06 11:27:40 DEBUG wire:72 - http-outgoing-0 >> "Host: link.bollore-logistics.com[\r][\n]"
2017-12-06 11:27:40 DEBUG wire:72 - http-outgoing-0 >> "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36[\r][\n]"
2017-12-06 11:27:40 DEBUG wire:72 - http-outgoing-0 >> "Accept-Language: en-US[\r][\n]"
2017-12-06 11:27:40 DEBUG wire:72 - http-outgoing-0 >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate[\r][\n]"
2017-12-06 11:27:40 DEBUG wire:72 - http-outgoing-0 >> "Accept: */*[\r][\n]"
2017-12-06 11:27:40 DEBUG wire:72 - http-outgoing-0 >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
2017-12-06 11:27:40 DEBUG wire:72 - http-outgoing-0 >> "[\r][\n]"
2017-12-06 11:27:41 DEBUG wire:72 - http-outgoing-0 << "HTTP/1.0 302 Found[\r][\n]"
2017-12-06 11:27:41 DEBUG wire:72 - http-outgoing-0 << "Location: https://link.bollore-logistics.com/Contact/SmartSearch/77707575[\r][\n]"
2017-12-06 11:27:41 DEBUG wire:72 - http-outgoing-0 << "Server: BigIP[\r][\n]"
2017-12-06 11:27:41 DEBUG wire:72 - http-outgoing-0 << "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
2017-12-06 11:27:41 DEBUG wire:72 - http-outgoing-0 << "Content-Length: 0[\r][\n]"
2017-12-06 11:27:41 DEBUG wire:72 - http-outgoing-0 << "[\r][\n]"
2017-12-06 11:27:41 DEBUG headers:113 - http-outgoing-0 << HTTP/1.0 302 Found
2017-12-06 11:27:41 DEBUG headers:116 - http-outgoing-0 << Location: https://link.bollore-logistics.com/Contact/SmartSearch/77707575
2017-12-06 11:27:41 DEBUG headers:116 - http-outgoing-0 << Server: BigIP
2017-12-06 11:27:41 DEBUG headers:116 - http-outgoing-0 << Connection: Keep-Alive
2017-12-06 11:27:41 DEBUG headers:116 - http-outgoing-0 << Content-Length: 0
2017-12-06 11:27:41 DEBUG MainClientExec:284 - Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
2017-12-06 11:27:41 DEBUG PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager:314 - Connection [id: 0][route: {}->http://link.bollore-logistics.com:80] can be kept alive indefinitely
2017-12-06 11:27:41 DEBUG PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager:320 - Connection released: [id: 0][route: {}->http://link.bollore-logistics.com:80][total kept alive: 1; route allocated: 1 of 6; total allocated: 1 of 20]
2017-12-06 11:27:41 DEBUG WebClient:1349 - Got a redirect status code [302] new location = [https://link.bollore-logistics.com/Contact/SmartSearch/77707575]
2017-12-06 11:27:41 DEBUG WebClient:1259 - Load response for GET https://link.bollore-logistics.com/Contact/SmartSearch/77707575
2017-12-06 11:27:41 DEBUG RequestAddCookies:122 - CookieSpec selected: mine
2017-12-06 11:27:41 DEBUG RequestAuthCache:76 - Auth cache not set in the context
2017-12-06 11:27:41 DEBUG PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager:249 - Connection request: [route: {s}->https://link.bollore-logistics.com:443][total kept alive: 1; route allocated: 0 of 6; total allocated: 1 of 20]
2017-12-06 11:27:41 DEBUG PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager:282 - Connection leased: [id: 1][route: {s}->https://link.bollore-logistics.com:443][total kept alive: 1; route allocated: 1 of 6; total allocated: 2 of 20]
2017-12-06 11:27:41 DEBUG MainClientExec:234 - Opening connection {s}->https://link.bollore-logistics.com:443
2017-12-06 11:27:41 DEBUG DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator:131 - Connecting to link.bollore-logistics.com/195.101.158.66:443
2017-12-06 11:27:41 DEBUG HtmlUnitSSLConnectionSocketFactory:335 - Connecting socket to link.bollore-logistics.com/195.101.158.66:443 with timeout 90000
2017-12-06 11:27:41 DEBUG HtmlUnitSSLConnectionSocketFactory:388 - Enabled protocols: [TLSv1]
2017-12-06 11:27:41 DEBUG HtmlUnitSSLConnectionSocketFactory:389 - Enabled cipher suites:[SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA]
2017-12-06 11:27:41 DEBUG HtmlUnitSSLConnectionSocketFactory:393 - Starting handshake
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1512530605 bytes = { 147, 117, 177, 152, 172, 87, 109, 103, 219, 130, 24, 140, 216, 108, 154, 3, 162, 211, 205, 89, 29, 221, 91, 103, 85, 39, 206, 187 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
***
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 161
0000: 01 00 00 9D 03 01 5A 27   63 AD 93 75 B1 98 AC 57  ......Z'c..u...W
0010: 6D 67 DB 82 18 8C D8 6C   9A 03 A2 D3 CD 59 1D DD  mg.....l.....Y..
0020: 5B 67 55 27 CE BB 00 00   36 00 04 00 05 00 2F C0  [gU'....6...../.
0030: 02 C0 04 C0 0C C0 0E C0   07 C0 09 C0 11 C0 13 00  ................
0040: 33 00 32 00 0A C0 03 C0   0D C0 08 C0 12 00 16 00  3.2.............
0050: 13 00 09 00 15 00 12 00   03 00 08 00 14 00 11 01  ................
0060: 00 00 3E 00 0A 00 34 00   32 00 17 00 01 00 03 00  ..>...4.2.......
0070: 13 00 15 00 06 00 07 00   09 00 0A 00 18 00 0B 00  ................
0080: 0C 00 19 00 0D 00 0E 00   0F 00 10 00 11 00 02 00  ................
0090: 12 00 04 00 05 00 14 00   08 00 16 00 0B 00 02 01  ................
00A0: 00                                                 .
http-bio-8080-exec-3, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 161
[Raw write]: length = 166
0000: 16 03 01 00 A1 01 00 00   9D 03 01 5A 27 63 AD 93  ...........Z'c..
0010: 75 B1 98 AC 57 6D 67 DB   82 18 8C D8 6C 9A 03 A2  u...Wmg.....l...
0020: D3 CD 59 1D DD 5B 67 55   27 CE BB 00 00 36 00 04  ..Y..[gU'....6..
0030: 00 05 00 2F C0 02 C0 04   C0 0C C0 0E C0 07 C0 09  .../............
0040: C0 11 C0 13 00 33 00 32   00 0A C0 03 C0 0D C0 08  .....3.2........
0050: C0 12 00 16 00 13 00 09   00 15 00 12 00 03 00 08  ................
0060: 00 14 00 11 01 00 00 3E   00 0A 00 34 00 32 00 17  .......>...4.2..
0070: 00 01 00 03 00 13 00 15   00 06 00 07 00 09 00 0A  ................
0080: 00 18 00 0B 00 0C 00 19   00 0D 00 0E 00 0F 00 10  ................
0090: 00 11 00 02 00 12 00 04   00 05 00 14 00 08 00 16  ................
00A0: 00 0B 00 02 01 00                                  ......
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 15 03 01 00 02                                     .....
[Raw read]: length = 2
0000: 02 28                                              .(
http-bio-8080-exec-3, READ: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
http-bio-8080-exec-3, RECV TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
http-bio-8080-exec-3, called closeSocket()
http-bio-8080-exec-3, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
2017-12-06 11:27:41 DEBUG DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection:87 - http-outgoing-1: Shutdown connection
2017-12-06 11:27:41 DEBUG MainClientExec:128 - Connection discarded
2017-12-06 11:27:41 DEBUG DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection:79 - http-outgoing-1: Close connection
2017-12-06 11:27:41 DEBUG PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager:320 - Connection released: [id: 1][route: {s}->https://link.bollore-logistics.com:443][total kept alive: 1; route allocated: 0 of 6; total allocated: 1 of 20]
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:174)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:136)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1694)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:939)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1120)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1147)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1131)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:394)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:353)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HtmlUnitSSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(HtmlUnitSSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:155)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:134)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:71)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpWebConnection.getResponse(HttpWebConnection.java:178)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseFromWebConnection(WebClient.java:1313)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseFromWebConnection(WebClient.java:1371)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponse(WebClient.java:1230)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:338)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:407)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:392)
    at com.grabber.Grabber.accessWebpage(Grabber.java:204)
    at com.grabber.Grabber.doGet(Grabber.java:53)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Comment: If you don't want it secure why are you using SSL at all?

Comment: I tried to access with webClient.getPage("http:// link.bollore-logistics.com"); only. But it will be redirect to https, so handshake failure will be thrown also. Even I removed the code of configuration. Handshake failure still exists

Comment: Not related to your probelm, but you might also want also to set `webClient.getOptions().setPopupBlockerEnabled(true)`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem (but not using HtmlUnit in that case. I used a directly a org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient).

It seams there is something wrong with the handshake **until java 7** (*no problem anymore in java 8*). If you try to access a server providing "TLSv1.2" you might get the error reported by you.

If security is not that much of an issue in your case, you can try the to force usage of TLSv1.1 (as long as you have not yet switched to java 8).
This shoud be possible this way:

```
   WebClientOptions webClientOptions= new WebClientOptions();
   webClientOptions.setSSLClientProtocols(new String[]{"TLSv1.1"});
   SSLConnectionSocketFactory.buildSSLSocketFactory(webClientOptions);
```

Comment: OP is on Java6 which doesn't implement TLS1.1 or 1.2 at all so they can't be enabled, plus a simple test shows the server here doesn't require 1.1 or 1.2 anyway.

Comment: *TLS1.1* is supported since  **JDK 6u111**  and *TLS1.2* since **JDK 6u115 b32** see http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview-156328.html#R160_121

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Sun/Oracle Java 6, since you didn't say IBM (which implements crypto differently):

Your problem is not ciphers (which BC-provider could fix only if the problem was lack of ECC ciphers), nor protocols. https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=link.bollore-logistics.com shows that server accepts ciphers and protocols that Java 6 could do without any augmentation.

**Your problem is SNI (Server Name Indication).** The ssllabs report shows that the only simulated clients that fail are the ones that don't send SNI (Android 2, Windows XP, Java 6) and a simple test with openssl confirms the server requires SNI. Java 6 JSSE did not implement SNI.

It might work to use the BC version of JSSE -- this is a separate jar `bctls-jdk15on-$ver` not `bcprov-jdk15on-$ver` and providername BCJSSE not BC. In the most recent versions (1.57 and 1.58) according to the source it appears to me the client should do SNI by default, if you connect using a domainname (not IPaddress or local alias). However I can't verify because I can't get BCJSSE to instantiate at all due to some problem with SecureRandom that I don't have time now to track down.